# Why are no keyframes created?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I am following along a tutorial.

In this tutorial, the tutor moves the camera, and this makes the camera position green in order to show that it has changed. Also, one can see how a keyframe was created.

[image]

When I try the same, nothing happens: No keyframe is created when I move an object around, and its position doesn't change its color.

What am I doing wrong?

My version:

[image]

Comment: You have to create an initial keyframe, either by pressing 'I' and selecting your required options, or hovering over the location in the N panel and pressing 'I'. When you then move the timeline marker the saved locations will change to green and you can move your object (which changes the location colour to orange) and press 'I' again. I don't know what video you're watching, but all decent beginner tutorial will explain that in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Green means that there is no keyframe *on the current frame* but there is one on some other frame *and* there have been no changes to the keyframed value. If there was a keyframe, it would be a dark yellow shade. If there was not one but the value was different it would be orange. Notice that the blue pointer above the timeline in the video is on a different frame than the one with the keyframe.

Since the dot next to the playback buttons is white in the video, it means the other person is *not* autokeying, so the only way they could have set a keyframe is to move the cursor to that particular frame and insert one manually.

You can do this by typing <kbd>I</kbd> **in the 3D Viewport** which will bring up a menu or by hovering over the transform settings, right clicking and selecting Insert Keyframe from the menu.

Comment: Thank you. What might be the reason that no keyframe appears when I type "i" and then select "All channels"?

Comment: Ahhh, I got it. Could you please add to your answer that the "i" needs to be pressed while the mouse pointer is in the upper window (not in the time line)?? And then "Insert keyframe menu -> Location". Else it would not work for me.

Comment: @tmighty I will when I get to my pc